# Oracle : How to write a SQL query to show serial numbers for each set of same values?

Tags: sql, oracle

For example if I have a table like 
EmpID , Empname , Country

Output should be like

```
EmpId   EmpName Country Serial No.
1       ABC     India         1
2       BCD     India         2
3       CMO     India         3
4       DIS     China         1
5       FGH     China         2
6       FHI     Singapore     1
7       XYZ     Singapore     2
8       KLM     Singapore     3
9       NOP     Singapore     4
10      QRS     Singapore     5
```

Here Group by Value is Country.

Comment: What have you tried so far????  Learn how to ask question!!!  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You are looking for `row_number()`

Comment: Read this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer myself . The following query would do.

```
SELECT EmpID , EmpName, Country , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY
Country order by EmpName ) AS GroupSequence1 from Employee;
```

Anymore further optimizations are welcomed

Comment: order by EmpId   is better than EmpName since EmpName is just dummy data.